Azure front door Custom domain automatically approved without validation
We are trying to create  custom domain  example: bb.aa.co.uk and cc.aa.co.uk existing Front Door profile which contains existing cusom domains (dd.aa.co.uk) but those newly created custom domains status  are directly going to Approved state instated of Pending or validation and not showing TXT records to update DNS.

In your case, the newly created custom domains (bb.aa.co.uk and cc.aa.co.uk) are skipping the validation phase and directly transitioning to the "Approved" state without showing the TXT record.If a wildcard domain (e.g., *.aa.co.uk) or a root domain (aa.co.uk) has already been validated, Azure Front Door may not require additional validation for subdomains (bb.aa.co.uk, cc.aa.co.uk).

@VenkatV How can we get the txt record, while we are creating the Azure frontdoor resources using  terraform it's failing
│ Error: expected length of record.0.value to be in the range (1 - 4096), got

Can you please share the Terraform code or raise a new issue with detailed requirement? I will try to resolve the issue.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.


Azure front door Custom domain automatically approved without validation.

The reason for newly created custom domains (bb.aa.co.uk and cc.aa.co.uk) skipping the validation and directly going to the "Approved" state without showing the TXT record. If a wildcard domain (e.g., *.aa.co.uk) or a root domain (aa.co.uk) has already been validated, the Azure Front Door may not require additional validation for subdomains (bb.aa.co.uk, cc.aa.co.uk)

Reference: Add a wildcard domain and certificate binding
